# How can I reduce a 20h render?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, volumetrics, denoise

I have followed a tutorial by Alaskan FX for a photorealistic Earth. This scene uses a 43k Clouds texture and 21k color map. My laptop is the Gigabyte g5 md with a RTX 3050 Ti 4gb and 16gb ram + 11400h i5. I use a different setting for the volume step size in the materials tab with 0.01 setted.

My render volume step rate was 0.25 where I had 20h of render time. With the default step rate of 1.00, I could reduce it to 4h, but it is still very hard for my laptop.

I only render it at 1080p with 4096 samples and default noise threshold. How can I reduce the render time without reducing any of the quality? I want it to be beautiful and clean, but not to a point, where it is just a waste of time.

Blender file https://fastupload.io/ktNYVUtXbkN2yWN/file

Edit: I got a notification, that another question might solve my problem, so that my question got taken down. But no, other questions related on that are either very old, or not related to my hardware specs.

Comment: The link to your Blend file says that the file has already been deleted.

Comment: the simple answer is: you can't. If you don't want to reduce quality, it is not possible. But...i strongly believe that if you lower the samples, you won't see a "real" difference. Just try it out! Render one pic with 4096 samples and one with 1000. I would bet, the difference isn't big.

Comment: same is right for noise threshold. but of course, i assume that you don't wanna zoom 10 times your result and you won't look with the hourglass for differences.

Comment: Have you even set to render using GPU in  preferences-> system ?

Comment: Also, 32 bounds is far more than necessary. Try reducing it (maybe 5 ?)

Answer (score 1):

1. One rule of thumb is to reduce the sample rate and try one or two test frames to see if it still works for you until a balance between speed and resolution is reached.
2. It may be counterintuitive but in the specific case of rendering volumes and step rate:"Higher values **reduce** render time".

Both lowering sample rate and increasing step rate reduce quality, but you have to make a compromise.